# cherrypick svn merge branch to trunk, followed by later merge with --reintegrate?

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

So I have this project with concurrent work going on in 2 releases, the trunk and branch1. At some point I am told "don't make any more builds for rel1, fix those bugs in rel2." So I make bugfixes in branch1 that could also apply to the trunk. Later I am told "It will be a big PITA if we relase rel1 with those known bugs. Please fix them in rel1 also."

So, my question is (~/rel1 is a current, unmodified working copy of the trunk. RevM, RevN are revision numbers in branch1 for a range of revisions that I want to merge back into the trunk):

If I do a

```
cd ~/rel1
svn merge -r RevM:RevN ^/branch1
```

how will it affect a later `svn merge --reintegrate` from the branch to the trunk? Bearing in mind that there are revisions in branch1 prior to `RevM` and there are going to be more after `RevN`. In particular, when I do eventually reintegrate, will it be as though I'd originally done the fixes in rel1 and merged them into rel2, as should have been done in the first place?

Comment: In the beginning of your question you mix up trunk, rel1, rel2, etc. a bit. Maybe you could fix this to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cherry-picking changes from a branch into trunk is something that is always twisting my mind as well. Here is a solution that should work in your case, the trick being to block the cherry-picked changes from being merged into the branch again.

```
cd ~/rel1
svn merge -r RevM:RevN ^/branch1
svn commit -m "cherry pick RevM:RevN from branch1 into rel1"
```

Now suppose this commit has created RevX. Go into your branch and block this revision from future merge actions by using the `--record-only`option.

```
cd ../branch1
svn merge -c RevX --record-only ^/rel1
svn commit -m "mark RevX as already merged to block it from future merge actions"
```

Now you should be able to merge further changes from `rel1`to `branch1` again as usual and also to reintegrate your branch into rel1 once you're done with it.

Comment: Note that this should work from svn 1.5 on. I've sometimes read that from 1.6 on svn should handle such cases a bit more clever - so maybe the blocking is not always necessary? I don't really know if that is indeed the case. I'll try to do a test scenario tomorrow.
Overall my feeling is that cherry-picking from a branch into trunk is not really well supported by the way svn works..

Comment: I'm going to accept this even though I'm not totally sure it's right. It begins to appear that the branch from which I was doing the merge is never going to be reintegrated, so I may never be able to ascertain what would have happened.